# Mapping intuitionistic logic to the modal logic S4

Tags: reference-request, logic

In his famous [Semantical Analysis of Intuitionistic Logic](https://www.princeton.edu/~hhalvors/restricted/kripke_intuitionism.pdf),
S. Kripke speaks of the "well-known mappings of intuitionistic logic
into the modal system S4". I'm not sure which mappings Kripke means.
One guess would be K. Gödel's "Eine Interpretation des
Intuitionistischen Aussagenkalküls" (translated into English as "An
Interpretation of the Intuitionistic Propositional Calculus". I don't have
access to either.)

Could somebody please point me towards a text that details these
translations?

Comment: By the way, while this is 100% on topic here, you'd probably get a better answer on the cstheory stack exchange.

Comment: Yes, I was torn where to ask the question. I guess it's really well-known and trivial. So I went for cs.stackexchange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the right paper, but there are actually several equivalent embeddings.

The book *Basic Proof Theory* by Troelstra and Schwichtenberg gives two such embeddings. Here's one. If $P$ is atomic but not $\bot$:

$$P^\circ := P$$
$$\bot^\circ := \bot$$
$$(A \wedge B)^\circ := A^\circ \wedge B^\circ$$
$$(A \vee B)^\circ := \square A^\circ \vee \square B^\circ$$
$$(A \rightarrow B)^\circ := \square A^\circ \rightarrow B^\circ$$
$$(\exists x A)^\circ := \exists x \square A^\circ$$
$$(\forall x A)^\circ := \forall x A^\circ$$

Here's the other:

$$P^\square := \square P$$
$$\bot^\square := \bot$$
$$(A \wedge B)^\square := A^\square \wedge B^\square$$
$$(A \vee B)^\square := A^\square \vee B^\square$$
$$(A \rightarrow B)^\square := \square (A^\square \rightarrow B^\square)$$
$$(\exists x A)^\square := \exists x A^\square$$
$$(\forall x A)^\square := \square \forall x A^\square$$

They are equivalent in the sense that $S4 \vdash \square A^\circ \leftrightarrow A^\square$, and the embeddings are sound and faithful. The proofs are left as an exercise, or you can dig out the book.

Comment: I have that book, and I even looked at its index before I asked my question, but the entry "intuistic logic" does not point towards anything useful. I should have looked at the table of content instead.

Comment: Correction (comparing the above answer to §9.2.1 and §9.2.2 on page 288 of the second edition of Troelstra&Schwhichtenberg): $P^□$ is defined as $□P$ for atomic $P$, and the equivalence is that $S4⊢□A^∘↔A^□$.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the two translations Pseudonym mentions in his/her reply, I found
another one [here](http://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Publications/Reports/PP-2006-25.text.pdf): It's from intuitionistic propositional logic to GL, the
[logic of provability](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/). GL is characterised by the following axioms.

- $\square(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow \square A \rightarrow \square B$.

  $\square A \rightarrow A$.

  $\square A \rightarrow \square \square A$.

  $\square (\square A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow \square A$.

Now the embedding is given by the following clauses.

- $p^{\triangle} := p \wedge \square p$.

  $\bot^{\triangle} := \bot$.

  $(A \wedge B)^{\triangle} := A^{\triangle} \wedge B^{\triangle}$.

  $(A \vee B)^{\triangle} := A^{\triangle} \vee B^{\triangle}$.

  $(A \rightarrow B)^{\triangle} := ( A^{\triangle} \rightarrow B^{\triangle}) \wedge \square ( A^{\triangle} \rightarrow B\
  ^{\triangle})$.

We can show that $\vdash A$ in intuitionistic propositional logic iff
$\vdash_{GL} A^{\triangle}$ in GL.